# How to access a global variable in two php files?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a variable in file1.php:

```
global $name;
$name = "";
```

In file2.php which is in the same directory I have

```
<label>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username" value ="<?php echo $GLOBALS['name'];?>" placeholder="Enter your user name" maxlength="20" />
</label>
```

I have read the similar questions and user manual but still I have doubt! I tried using session but it did not work for me. How can I access this variable?

Comment: You could include you file1 in file2

Comment: ^--« you just asked this not 20 mins ago. (exact duplicate)

Comment: Avoid using `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This question is different from that one. That was not about global variable. I was trying to parse a value but here I am trying to read it from different file!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need **global**, as the variable `$name` is not inside any function. Eventhough it is inside a function pass this `$name` as a parameter to it.

**file1.php**

```
<?php
$name = "PHP rocks";
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
include_once('file1.php'); //<---- Just include the above file inside this
?>
<label>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username" value ="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="Enter your user name" maxlength="20" />
</label>
```

Comment: Reason for the downvote and may I know why you love **global** ?

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are declared and loaded into memory at runtime. That means that for your global `$name` to exist in any scope, `file1.php` must have been parsed first.

As the commenter pointed out, your solution is to include `file1.php` *before* `file2.php` runs.